# What does "Error receiving broadcast Intent {....}" mean?

Tags: android

My app includes a service which receives locations via broadcasts, and there is also an activity that registers for those same broadcasts. Intermittently, and apparently only on some devices, the activity blows up with this:

```
class java.lang.RuntimeException
Msg: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.company.app.ACTION_LOCATION_CHANGED flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.company.app.library.activity.MyActivity$LocationReceiver@40f45bb8
```

I cannot use the debugger to look at the app's state as I cannot reproduce this error, so I'm reliant on analytics logs.

What does this exception actually mean? i.e. what is the problem in receiving it?

Comment: how to  resolve this issue ? i have also facing this err on receiver.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This means that there is an uncaught exception inside onReceive method.
Take a look on what can cause it... difficult to say without code and without more detailed stacktrace.

Answer (score 18):

Another possibility is that there's more information a bit further down the log.

Example: I just had this error, and the log data looked like:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE flg=0x10 (has extras) } in myAppName.BlunoLibrary$5@41f792f8
    at LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:778)
    at Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    ...bunch of internal android stuff...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at myAppName.MainActivity.onSerialReceived(MainActivity.java:96) <-- hey look, my code screwed up!
    at myAppName.BlunoLibrary$5.onReceive(BlunoLibrary.java:327)
    at LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:768)
    at Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
    ...bunch of other normal-looking callstack stuff...
```

That secondary "caused by" gave a very straightforward location where I had made a mistake.

Comment: that really helped me get to the exact problem

Answer (score 4):

Another possible reason is that you are not unregistering the receiver in the activity's onPause() method.